# Using interpolation to derive a function in R

Tags: r, math, spline

I'm trying to derive an approximated function from some X and Y values in R. 
As I understand it splines can be used, but I just can't grasp how through the documentation.

Heres what I'd like to do:

```
x <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(200, 320, 455, 612, 899)
## Example of goal
approxfun <- findfun(x,y, pow=5)
approxfun
```

Returning a result of: f(x) = y = a*x^5 + b*x^4 + c*x^3 + d*x^2 + e*x^1 + f. 
Where a, b, c, d, e, and f are some real numbers.

The core issue I'm trying to tackle is solving an equation in the form of sum(f(x)),n=1->N = max. IE. I'm trying to find the N that allows for the maximum amount of accumulated function sums of f(x). In other words, if i have 100 apples and eat increasing amounts each day as they being to turn over-ripe, and the amount i eat each day is f(x), I need to know how many days the apples will last.

Comment: If you eat `y[i]` apples on day i then and there are 1000 apples then they will last for `sum(cumsum(y) < 1000) + 1` days.  This gives 4 days for the data in the question.

Comment: Sure, the problem is that I don't know what y[i] is, i only have data for 5 days and want to extrapolate by approximating f(x) with a polynomial of degree n.

Comment: That's not what the question says.